Where to find IC footprint lookup tables
Back when I was at university, there was a PCB technician assigned to our lab, who had books containing lookup tables for various IC footprints, showing both the size and a to-scale illustration of each footprint.
I cannot find any such books anymore - Anybody know of such books, who can suggest a title or author?

https://www.ebay.com/b/Texas-Instruments-Electronic-Components-Books-Manuals/41519/bn_17640803, https://www.ebay.com/itm/164986251338

Was going to VTC this obvious list-question, but I see it got the blessings of a diamond mod, what the...?

As Barry pointed out, these books are no longer distributed. You can still find PDFs of them, I searched for "integrated circuit footprint pdf" and found these ones:

brtchip
FTDI

Edit:
Found this poster from nexperia:


Years ago, most IC vendors published data books (usually at no cost) that gave this information on their parts. Unfortunately, these books are no longer being distributed. Instead the information is on each vendor's website which saves them considerable time and money.

There are package drawings available from the manufacturers. Sometimes, but not always, they will provide a recommended or suggested footprint for your PCB design, especially if the package is unusual or new at the time of publication.
Commercial EDA tools such as Altium provide tools that create footprints in compliance with IPC-7351   recommendations once you (somewhat tediously) key in the various max/min dimensions for the package and the leads. For Kicad there is a footprint generator, not sure how great it is at this point.

Not sure if this is still the case, but I remember OrCAD didn't have a QFN option in their footprint generator. Instead, what you had to do, was create an LQFP package with negative distance between the body and pads.

@jaskij I have not used OrCAD in quite a few years (stopped right around the time they changed the PCB format completely), but my recollection is that development virtually halted but it was sold for many years afterward.

Honestly, I think Cadence keep the PCB design stuff around just so they can tell their chip design customers "you can do everything from IC layout to PCB layout in the same suite of tools". Also, my foray into it was very short, thankfully.

JEDEC standardizes packages for commodity parts, especially for memories but also other common package types such as SO-xx, DO-xx and TO-xx.
That said, with the great variety of IC parts these days and with new ones being introduced frequently, it isn't practical to have a single 'book' for them all. Such a 'book' would not only be unwieldy, but would be quickly out of date.
Instead, you'll have to seek out the footprints as you need them from databases that are maintained and updated regularly.
Where to look? At worst case you will use the manufacturer's datasheet to create your own footprints as needed.
Some manufacturers will take the extra step and helpfully provide schematic and layout e-CAD data from their own websites and well as though resellers like DigiKey or Mouser.
There are also third party e-CAD repositories. Have a look these:

SnapEDA
Ultra Librarian
KiCAD Libraries
Component Search Engine
PCB Libraries

More here: https://www.electronics-lab.com/top-10-websites-to-find-footprints-for-your-next-pcb-project/
Once you've found the footprints you need, regardless of where you got them it's still incumbent on you to check them for correctness (e.g., right pinout and shape) and for manufacturability (including compliance with IPC-7351.) As often as not, there will be a need to edit the footprints to resolve those issues.

As others say, IC databooks and other component catalogs are long gone - the information formerly printed in databooks is now available as .pdf documents for download.
The datasheets for most ICs will have the package dimensions and recommended footprint, although some may refer to a separate document for this information.
Do a web search for "[IC part number] datasheet" to find the datasheet - try to get it from the IC manufacturer, rather than from a third party.

As one example, TI have the Find TI packages page which is organised around different types of Package Families. E.g. Die-Size Ball Grid Array (WCSP) (DSBGA). For each type of Package Family there is one page linked from the main one which has links to links to the package drawing for each size of package.
On clicking a selection of package drawings:

Each one has the dimensions of the package and leads / pins.
Some have a recommended land pattern for the PCB.

